# Android Studio debugger throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

This problem started yesterday, I try and press the "Debug" button for an app and In the event log I see:

```
11:24:34 AM NullPointerException: null
```

and my app wouldn't start.
I'm trying to debug on the Emulator, I tried restarting both AS and computer with no help.

If I run the app normally it works fine. Needless to say that 2 days ago same code debugged fine

Anyone has a clue what this might be?

**Edit:**

That is the only error that appears in the log.

```
11:30:49 AM Platform and Plugin Updates: A new version of Android Studio is available! (show balloon)
11:31:11 AM Gradle sync started
11:32:07 AM Gradle sync completed
11:32:07 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
11:32:26 AM Gradle build finished in 18s 592ms
11:34:12 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
11:34:22 AM Gradle build finished in 10s 315ms
11:34:51 AM NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: have you updated your AS to 2.0?

Comment: I thought of that, downloading it right now. It's currently 1.5.

Comment: no, a lot of people here got problems After updating to 2.0... please show more from error log

Comment: There is nothing else. That's the only thing that shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Android Studio 1.5 into 2.0 solved the problem. Perhaps even if I re-installed 1.5 it would have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

stop debugger and clean project may help